# Calculate rectangle's side length from fitted ellipse and area data

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The *problem* is the following:

> Let there be a rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$ and diagonal $d$. Let
>   there be an ellipse with axes $x$ and $y$.
>
> The areas of the two shapes are the same. The ellipse was fitted to
>   the rectangle so the centroid of the two shapes is the same, their
>   orientation is the same (axes are parallel and "on top of" each
>   other). Given $d$, $x$, $y$ and the area, can we calculate $a$ and $b$?

Thanks!

Comment: What's mean by "fitted"?  Unlikely to be one inscribing the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area (or $x$ and $y$) will give you the product of $a$ and $b$. $d$ will give you the sum of their squares. Using $(a+b)^2= a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$, you can solve for $a$ and $b$.